# Binding is working differently if used with sheet or navigation link

Tags: ios, swift, binding, swiftui

I try to use data binding within my view hierarchy. Depending how I call my subview the binding is working as expected.

Working example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

final class PersonStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var persons: [Person] = [
        .init(id: .init(), name: "Dirk", age: 28),
        .init(id: .init(), name: "John", age: 31),
        .init(id: .init(), name: "Fred", age: 25)
    ]
}


struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var store = PersonStore()

    @State var isEditing = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List (store.persons.indices) { index in
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(store.persons[index].name)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("Age: \(store.persons[index].age)")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        Text("Index \(index)")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Edit", action: {
                        isEditing.toggle()
                    })
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isEditing) {
                    NavigationView {
                        EditingView(person: $store.persons[index])
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Persons")
        }
    }
}

struct EditingView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @Binding var person: Person
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Personal information")) {
                TextField("type something...", text: $person.name)
                Stepper(value: $person.age) {
                    Text("Age: \(person.age)")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: saveButton)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(person.name))
    }
    
    var saveButton: some View {
        Button(action: dismiss) {
            Text("Cancel")
        }
    }
    
    func dismiss() {
        
        self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When I replace the `sheet` view with a `NavigationLink` view, then the binding is broken.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var store = PersonStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List (store.persons.indices) { index in
                NavigationLink(destination: EditingView(person: $store.persons[index])) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(store.persons[index].name)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("Age: \(store.persons[index].age)")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        Text("Index \(index)")
                        
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Persons")
        }
    }
}
```

The data in the `EditingView` is no longer directly updated. Only if I navigate back to the list, the changed data is shown.

Any ideas, where the binding is lost?

Comment: Also, the name is not modified in the `.navigationBarTitle (Text (person.name))` when the `TextField` is modified. A very interesting post.

Comment: I'm running into this, did you ever figure out what was up with it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still wondering why this happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `PersonStore` as `@ObservedObject` object directly to subView, with index value parameter, instead of try and handling binding individually for each object. So, any change directly in `persons` array in  `PersonStore`, will trigger notification to update all views marked with `@ObservedObject` having `PersonStore`.

```
     import SwiftUI
    
    
    struct Person: Identifiable {
        let id: UUID
        var name: String
        var age: Int
    }
    
    final class PersonStore: ObservableObject {
        @Published var persons: [Person] = [
            .init(id: .init(), name: "Dirk", age: 28),
            .init(id: .init(), name: "John", age: 31),
            .init(id: .init(), name: "Fred", age: 25)
        ]
    }
    
    
    struct ContentViewsss: View {
        
        @ObservedObject var store = PersonStore()
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List (store.persons.indices) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditingView(personStore: store,index:index)) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(store.persons[index].name)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text("Age: \(store.persons[index].age)")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            Text("Index \(index)")
                            
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("Persons")
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct EditingView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @ObservedObject var personStore: PersonStore
    @State private var textValue = ""
    @State private var stepper = 0
    var index:Int

    init(personStore:PersonStore,index:Int) {
        self.personStore = personStore
        self.index = index
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Personal information")) {
                TextField("type something...", text: $personStore.persons[index].name)
                    
                Stepper(value: $personStore.persons[index].age) {
                    Text("Age: \(personStore.persons[index].age)")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: saveButton)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(personStore.persons[index].name))
    }

    var saveButton: some View {
        Button(action: dismiss) {
            Text("Cancel")
        }
    }

    
    func dismiss() {

        self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves the issue, but did not explain, why the binding is broken, when I switch between sheet and navigation view. Also, I don"t like the idea top pass the store. If  this is the goal, I would go with an Environment Object